# Is this quote a reference to something: "Tout est mauvais! C'est un festival!"

Tags: reference, les-visiteurs-revolution

During one scene in *[Les visiteurs: la révolution](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2441982/)* a character says

> Tout est mauvais! C'est un festival!
>   ("Everything's wrong! It's a festival!")

Is this a reference to something else? If so, what? I mean, I think it is a fun reference to an external source, but can't remember which.

It's probably a french reference. I've included a video from the movie in [this tweet](https://twitter.com/WikiSamuel/status/764888868864847873) (french).

Comment: I'm really not sure what you're asking. Can you please explain more completely?

Comment: @Catija - He's asking what that quote is a reference to.

Comment: However, @SamuelTb - It might be helpful if you can give us the context of the quote (who said it, about what, to whom, etc.). Thanks!

Comment: What is it about the line that makes you think it references something else ... as someone with a very basic grasp of french, I can't hear anything in the way he says it.  Does it just 'ring a bell' for you?

Comment: Thanks. The character says to the innkeeper that the meal is bad. @iandotkelly yes, the quote « C'est un festival ! » and the way he says so sounds familiar to me.